# Multi-Record list button run from a list view filtered by Topic causes NoAccessException

Tags: custom-button, list-view, filters, topics

I have added a multi-record list button to the *Contact* object that forwards the selected records to a custom VisualForce page that is defined below.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="selectedContacts">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb" title="Selected Contacts">
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbTable" value="{!selected}" var="c">                    
                <apex:column value="{!c.id}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This button works as expected in most cases. However, when a *Topic* filter (screenshot below) is used on the *Contact* list view I get the following exception when clicking on the button:

```
system.security.NoAccessException: Object type not accessible. 
Please check permissions and make sure the object is not in development mode: 
Contact WHERE ( ((Topics INCLUDES 'Demo')) AND (id IN ('003F000001LLMhJIAX' 
^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:88 expecting a left parentheses, found 'Demo'
```

**Screenshot of the Topic filter**

[image: Screenshot of the Topic filter]

**Question:**
What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Using `INCLUDES` in queries typically requires an array of comma delimited values and I would have expected to see it written as `Contact WHERE ( ((Topics INCLUDES ('Demo') )) AND ` even though there is just a single value in the list. This is also consistent with the error message. Is this a query which you created in code or is it auto-generated by the List View's filter criteria? Can you add a picture of the Filter Criteria on your view?

Comment: Hmmm, this looks like a bug in the StandardSetController to me.

Comment: Just been looking to see if I can reproduce this, can you include a screenshot of your List View definition please?

Comment: @Pond The filter is from a standard list view. I have added a screenshot of the filter to the question.

Comment: I've also opened a case with Salesforce. No response yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior has been identified as a bug by Salesforce.

Track the status of this issue [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4CjAAK/).